# Resample and interpolate time series data in Python only when difference between timestamp not greater than certain threshold

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

See sample data as below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'timestamp': pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-01-01 00:10:00', '2023-01-01 00:20:00', '2023-01-01 00:40:00', '2023-01-01 00:50:00', '2023-01-01 01:10:00']), 
'value': [10, 20, 30, 50, 60, 80]
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My data is sampled every 10 minutes normally, but there could be gaps in the timstamp. I'd like to resample the data every second, and interpolate the result, only when the difference between timestamp is no greater than 10 minutes. In the example shown, I'd like to resample and interpolate only 2023-01-01 00:00:00 to 2023-01-01 00:20:00, and 2023-01-01 00:40:00 to 2023-01-01 00:50:00. The rest should be removed.

Currently I'm running a for loop to iterate over the dataframe, although I understand it's not the efficient and elegant way to do so. Is there a better way without iterating over the dataframe?

```
data['gap'] = data['timestamp'].diff() > pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)

sections = []
current_section = []
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['gap']:
        if current_section:
            sections.append(current_section)
            current_section = []
    current_section.append(row)
sections.append(current_section)

resampled_data = []
for section in sections:
    section = pd.DataFrame(section)
    if len(section) > 1:
        start_time = section.iloc[0]['timestamp']
        end_time = section.iloc[-1]['timestamp']
        section_resampled = section.set_index('timestamp').resample('1S').interpolate(method='linear')
        section_resampled = section_resampled.loc[start_time:end_time]
        resampled_data.append(section_resampled)

resampled_data = pd.concat(resampled_data)
resampled_data = resampled_data.drop(columns='gap')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `df` filtered by no greater than 10 minutes

Groups are divided whenever the time interval exceeds 10 minutes, and the group with the number of groups equal to 1 is filtered out.

```
g = data['timestamp'].diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('10min')).cumsum()
df = data.groupby(g).filter(lambda x: x['value'].count() > 1)
```

`df`

```
    timestamp           value
0   2023-01-01 00:00:00 10
1   2023-01-01 00:10:00 20
2   2023-01-01 00:20:00 30
3   2023-01-01 00:40:00 50
4   2023-01-01 00:50:00 60
```

divide group by `g` and resample by 1s and interpolate and concat

```
result = pd.concat([df.groupby(g).get_group(x).resample(rule='1S', on='timestamp').mean().interpolate(method='linear') for x in df.groupby(g).groups])
```

Let's check if it's right

```
# resampled_data is variable in your post
result.equals(resampled_data)
```

True